# Using C# Is there any possibility to get only User created Libraries(List) in sharepoint 2013 client object model

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Recently I am working on project that requires to programmatically get user created SharePoint document libraries.
I tried by below code where "_site.Lists" property returning predefined libraries also(like "Documnets","Site Assests","Form Templates"...).But i need only user created libraries.
Is there any way to differentiate between user created library and predefined library(libraries created while configuring sharepoint site)

```
        private readonly ClientContext _clientContext;
        private readonly Web _site; 

        _clientContext = new ClientContext(sharePointSiteUrl);
        _site = _clientContext.Web;
        _clientContext.Load(_site);
        _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        //Get documnet libraries
        _clientContext.Load(_site.Lists);
        _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
         ListCollection docLibs =  docLibs = _site.Lists;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have tried by checking properties of each library,i didn't find any property that differentiate between user created and predefined library.I didn't find any property to find it's creator.

Comment: What do you mean by "User Created"  vs "PreDefined Library. Do you mean the libraries / lists created by Site definition / Site Templates as Predefined libraries, Do you include Libraries / Lists created by activation of Site Features as also "Pre defined " libraries ? And only those lists that are created using Add an App option as user created ?

Comment: Thanks Godwin for the response, My SharePoint site contains total 10 document libraries, in which 3 are by default created by share point (those are Documents, Site Assests etc), remaining are created by sharepoint administrator, in this case, using Client object model API, i need to get the document libraries created by sharepoint administrator.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Seems crazy that they would not differentiate between system and user generated folders, but I don't see anything obvious. I want to show my users just the ones they have created, not all libraries...